# Show that if $f : A → B$ is injective and $g_1$, $g_2$ : $B → A$ $:$ $g_1\circ f=$: $g_2\circ f$ implies $g_1$=$g_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, discrete-mathematics

How can i start?
I don't understand how to use that $f$ is injective but I had thought to show f is the inverse of $ g_1 $ and arrive at $g_1 = g_2$

Comment: It seems that the problem statement is incomplete. For instance, if A={1,2} and B={1,2,3}, f is the identity, g1 sends 1,2 to 1 and 3 to 2, while g2 identically maps to 1, then $g_1\circ f$ sends 1,2 both back to 1, as does $g_2\circ f$.

Comment: As zjs points out, what you have written is not true. 
It is true if $f$ is surjective (onto). If you mean injective (one to one), then you need to reverse the order of composition (ie, have $fg_1 = fg_2$).